# Proper word for "angry"?

Tags: vocabulario

I've started learning Spanish using duolingo a couple months ago. There, the word for "angry" is *enojado*.

I've used that word in a conversation with my friend (from Catalunya). He told me that it's "south american slang".

What is the proper word then?

Comment: "molesto" as in "upset" or angry

Comment: *Slang*? I wouldn't follow that person's advice on language too closely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already answered by @Danielillo, *enfadado* is most likely the word your friend had in mind, although *enojado* is a perfectly proper word to use.

The use of Spanish and its words is incredibly diverse, as it is spread throughout multiple continents. Duolingo teaches a somewhat neutral Spanish. It tends to use the words that are more common in Latin America. The proper word for ***you*** is going to be the one used wherever you would like to speak Spanish. If your goal is to speak with people like your friend, please listen to the nitpicks they might mention to you, otherwise disregard it. Duolingo can be a bit awkward at times but Spanish is one of their top languages; they're most likely not going to have a blatant error on such a high profile language.

Comment: Está excelente. Esto es exactamente lo que quise decir y no hay forma más acertada y concisa de decirlo!

Comment: (+1) I’ve always found choosing the right word to express the right amount of emotion quite hard. Even when I ask my Cuban friends about it I get different answers, I’ve heard *incomodo* a lot but never been sure exactly how it translates or where it fits on a scale between eg molestado > furioso, passing through say fastidiado, irritado, contrariado, enfadado, enojado and cabreado on the way :-)

Comment: @Traveller Devil's in the nuance. Although, _incomodo_ is exactly the same as _uncomfortable_. Both have the prefix and root: not-comfort.  The other words you mention are more about frustration than discomfort.

Comment: @Edwar That’s exactly the problem - I know *incomodo* means *uncomfortable* but as a native English speaker I rarely use the word *uncomfortable* and pretty much never use it to mean anything approaching angry/annoyed. But my Cuban friend says *¿Estás incomoda? a lot when we’re having a disagreement/argument and in that context I’m pretty sure he’s not asking if I’m uncomfortable :-) I don’t recall him ever using *enojada* or *enfadado* TBH

Answer (score 7):

*Enojado* is not slang, just more used in SA than in Spain. The most common word in Spain is *enfadado*.

In any case, there are millions of Spanish speakers in the world, and many of them may have a different word for each case. So, better to follow a learning language application advice than **just a person** from Catalonia

Comment: No. Es al contrario, sabio es seguir los consejos de una persona que maneje el idioma. El último lugar del que aprendería es de una aplicación o de un libro. Ya que solo reflejan la intención purista de quién lo escribió para ‘hacerse el neutral’. No hay nada peor que eso. En todo caso, vas a aprender a hablar pero prácticamente como un robot, con discursos vacíos y que no reflejen ninguna personalidad. No hay peor estrategia que la que mencionaste para aprender.

Comment: Creo que tu consideración acerca de mi consejo es algo fundamentalista, como muchas de tus apreciaciones. En ningún caso he mencionado alguna estrategia de aprendizaje porque no soy ningún profesional del tema ni tampoco ofrezco dogmas como respuestas. Recomendaría mayor amplitud de criterio, tanto en respuestas como en comentarios.

Comment: @tac ¿De quién son los consejos que sigo sobre el verbo "coger"?  Una persona de españa, o una de méxico?  Los dos usan muy diferente esa palabra.

Comment: @PeterM Sí, eso es obvio. Y debido a eso, no podemos declarar ningún español como ‘neutro’. Sin embargo, muchos piensan lo contrario. Y por eso aprenden a hablar con las aplicaciones y mirando dibujitos, pero esto es una versión que *también es sesgada* y que está lejos de ser universal. Por ejemplo, una vez vi en Duolingo que le llamaban ‘pastel’ a la torta. A ver, dale, vení a la Argentina y pedí ‘pastel’ a ver si alguien te entiende algo.

Comment: @PeterM Entonces, no me malinterpretes. Las aplicaciones y libros sirven pero para aprender reglas generales, gramaticales, etc. Pero si es por vocabulario y encima tenés a un nativo al lado ¿cómo no vas a aprovechar para sacarle el jugo y preguntarle de cada cosa cómo le dicen en su lugar? La respuesta de Danielillo parece sostener la opinión contraria, y menester es ponerlo en evidencia.